# Styling forth level menu item not working

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out why the forth level is not styling. Can someone please help with this CSS spaghetti?

[Fiddler: Menu Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YZb7y/4/)

Comment: It is. Your window isn't wide enough.

Comment: The fourth level is highlighted even though I am only hovering on the third level. I can't remove the stuck hover effect on the fourth level.

Comment: Probably due to the `!important` abuse I see in your CSS spaghetti.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems with this. For starters I strongly suggest that you clean up your CSS and Validate your HTML.

This is invalid in your CSS, which is part of the problem.

```
.nav ul li li li:hover a {
background:#00999b url(img/arrow_over.gif) no-repeat 95% 9px !important; 
}
```

And this HTML is invalid: You have unclosed tags inside of other tags.

```
<ul>
            <li class="canieti first"><a href="#"><span>***HOME</span></a><ul>
            <li class="quienessomos first"><a href="#"><span>***SECOND</span></a><ul>
            <li class="consejodirectivonacional"><a href="#"><span>***THIRD</span></a><ul>
            <li class="mesadirectivanacional first"><a href="#"><span>***FOURH</span></a></li>
         </ul>

            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="canieti first"><a href="#"><span>Other</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```